# Add onclick="return false" to the link

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add onclick="return false" java script code to link with specific attribute..

but not working..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $('#mysLink').click(function(){ MyFunction(); return false; });

</script>
```

and html code:

```
<a id="mysLink" href="http://facenama.com">.روفور RAV4.</a>
```

Comment: what is not working? What do you expect?

Comment: `MyFunction();` what's this function for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason, why you cannot just use

```
event.preventDefault()
```

in your function 'MyFunction'.

Comment: this? $('#mysLink').click(function(){ MyFunction(event.preventDefault()); return false; });

Comment: $('#mysLink').click(function(event){ 
      event.preventDefault();
      ... other code 
      })
Simply forget about return false, as I recall, it won't work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It should work (not follow the link) if your `MyFunction` is working fine and doesn't break before `return false` is executed. If you comment out your function it should work as expected and would prove that smth is wrong with that function (check console log for errors)